# Default value for one of several keys in an object you get as parameter

Tags: javascript

I got a function:

```
const doSomething= (person) => {
// Some code... 
}
```

that gets this object as a parameter:

```
const person = {
name: 'Daniel',
Age: 34,
City: 'Dresden'
}
```

To handle a case where `city` is `undefined`,
how can I give only this specific `city` key default value? Not the entire object like this:

```
const doSomething= (person = null) => {
// Some code... 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handle a case where city is undefined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `person` argument, destructure it into `name,`, `Age`, and `City`, and assign a default value to `City`:

```
const doSomething = ({ name, Age, City = 'default city' }) => {
  // Some code... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CertainPerformance answer; or you can do in the function

```
person.City = person.City || ''
```

putting instead of `''` the default value you want. Leaving `''` makes `City` a `string` with default value `empty string`.